# Inline Images, Quotes etc

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how you markup inline images. I have a `h2` tag and a `span` tag inside of that, so :

```
<h2>John Smith <span>Head of Communications</span</h2>
```

inside the `span` tag I'd like to put an the twitter symbol with the person's twitter details next to it (in the same sentence).

Also, would like to have quotes and do the pretty much the same thing within `<p>` tags which is probably the same solution.

How would I mark this up? I understand it's probably very simple but haven't done it before weirdly enough, and there's only one way to learn, ask.

Comment: There's another way to learn: _doing it_. Have you anything you've tried so far? :)

Comment: Twitter details as a separate image or in plain text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<h2>John Smith <img src="Image link here" /> Head of Communications</h2>
```

Should be fine. Works in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BgZjN/

Will work in p tags also

Answer (score 1):

```
<h2>John Smith <span style="background: url(***TwitterSymbol.png***); display: block;">Head of Communications</span></h2>
```

With the use of CSS background you can easily attach the logo of twitter beside the text.
Simply replace TwitterSymbol.png with the twitter logo URL you would like to use. The display block is necessary for the background image to appear. If ever the background still does not appear, try adding a specific height and width in the inline CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to wrap all the elements (images) you want to place inline with `<span></span>` tag. And then, you should add a CSS attribute to span wrappers: `display: inline-block;` (if I not mistaken). Also additional `overflow: hidden;` may help.